# Как работает mysql при одновременных запросах

Tags: mysql

Допустим запрос длится 1 секунду, если в это время другой человек послал запрос он выполнится или будет ждать завершения от 1 человека?
И транзакция блокирует таблицу для всех пользователей или только для текущего до завершения запроса?

Comment: Было бы печально если бы ожидало, впрочем для некоторых ситуаций так и есть.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Каждый запрос обрабатывается отдельным соединением - т.е. параллельно. Если один запрос не блокирует другой запрос, они выполняются независимо друг от друга. Если параллельных соединений много, то может случиться ситуация, когда все соединеия будут исчерпаны. Их количество определяется директивой `max_connections` (обычно несколько сотен). Если соединение блокируется - оно ожидает, когда нужные участки таблицы (InnoDB) или сама таблица (MyISAM) освободятся. В этот момент соединение не доступно и обслуживается другими свободными соединениями. Если блокировок много и много потоков ждут, соединения начинают заканчиваться и на обслуживание быстрых запросов остается мало соединений. Если соединения вообще закончились и мы уперлись в потолок `max_connections` сервер дает отлуп на новые запросы и просто их не обрабатывает, возвращая ошибку "Too many connections". Бесконечно увеличивать размер соединений нельзя, так как каждое потребляет оперативную память и не мало, порядка нескольких мегабайт, в зависимости от настроек в my.cnf.

Блокировки, как правило, случаются только при записи и обновлении. Чем быстрее выполняются запросы - тем меньше времени происходит блокировка и тем быстрее выполняются остальные запросы. Чем быстрее выполняются запросы - тем быстрее они освобождают соединения для других запросов. Поэтому обычно основная задача разработчика - добиться как можно более быстрого выполнения запросов. Если в системе много блокирующих запросов (как правило, на запись) - она начинает загибаться, копится очередь ожидающих соединений, исчерпывается оперативная память, даже если потом блокировка снимается, накопившиеся запросы все-равно нужно выполнять.

Comment: А какой запрос может блокировать другой запрос, и как на счет транзакций как они себя ведут при одновременных запросах от разных пользователей?

Comment: Как правило, блокируют запросы на обновление и запись. Причем в случае MyISAM  блокируется вся таблица. В случае InnoDB участок от первой записи до исправляемой. В транзакциях очень много зависит от того, что за запросы в транзакции и какой уровень изоляции включен (допускаются ли фантомные чтения).